# Creating sub categories

Tags: feature-selection, exploratory-factor-analysis

I have data we have collected quarterly over the last two years from two organisations. They are collected via the use of 29 questions. For each organisation, there are about 500 answers per question. The number which is produced for each quarter, question and organisation is an average score (1-10). Example of 5 questions is below:

[image]

The issue I am trying to solve is the second column. We use these tags to create a sub category or score. However, having run correlation analysis there are some questions that have no correlation with the other questions in the sub category (i.e. role).

I have run factor analysis which has produced some interesting results. However, this only works when the same organisation is considered are there is very little relationship between the two organisations.Therefore creating a global score is very difficult.

Is there a better way to create more appropriate tags for column 2. I have also considered feature selection.

thanks.